# Basis and dimensions of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Basically I know how to determine the basis and dimension of a real vector space or subspace, but I need to know how can I determine the basis and dimension of a complex subspace as Complex and as Real. Example: 
Let $V=\{( z,t )\in \mathbb{C} |t-4z=z-t \}$.
**Determine the Bases and Dimension of $V$ on $\mathbb{C}$ and on $\mathbb{R}$**. And how can I write the answer in the right way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The dimension over $\Bbb R$ will be twice that over $\Bbb C$

Comment: $\{1,i\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb R$

Comment: How would you determine the basis if it said $(z,t)\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner in this case the base of V= span {(5/2 , 1)} with dim(v)=1

Comment: same for $\Bbb C$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner i multipli it by ( 1,i ) so i obtain basis over real numbers, isn’t ?

Comment: Essentially yes

Answer (score 1):

You have the linear equation t- 4z= z- t (and it is to be understood that z and t are complex numbers).  That can easily be written as 2t= 5z.  Taking that common value to be "k", we can write (t, z)= (k/2, k/5). And since a vector space is closed under multiplication by scalars, 10(k/2, k/5)= (5k, 2k)= k(5, 2) is in the space for all k and every member of this space is equal to k(5, 2) for some k.  That is, with k any complex number, {(5, 2)} is a basis for the space and the dimension, over the complex numbers, is 1.

Since we can write k= a+ bi, with a and b real numbers, k(5, 2)= (a+ bi)(5, 2)= a(5, 2)+ b(5i, 2i).  As a vector space over the real numbers, a basis is {(5, 2), (5i, 2i)} and the dimension is 2.